# Convert color RGB to HEX (int result)

Tags: java, android

I've created a method that convert three integer values to an hex value (string), as you can see below (P.S.: it was not been tested yet):

```
protected String convertRGBToHex(int r, int g, int b) {

    String rFString, rSString, gFString, gSString, bFString, bSString, result;
    int red, green, blue;
    int rred, rgreen, rblue;

    red = r / 16;
    rred = r % 16;

    if (red == 10) rFString = "A";
    else if (red == 11) rFString = "B";
    else if (red == 12) rFString = "C";
    else if (red == 13) rFString = "D";
    else if (red == 14) rFString = "E";
    else if (red == 15) rFString = "F";
    else rFString = String.valueOf(red);

    if (rred == 10) rSString = "A";
    else if (rred == 11) rSString = "B";
    else if (rred == 12) rSString = "C";
    else if (rred == 13) rSString = "D";
    else if (rred == 14) rSString = "E";
    else if (rred == 15) rSString = "F";
    else rSString = String.valueOf(rred);

    rFString = rFString + rSString;

    green = g / 16;
    rgreen = g % 16;

    if (green == 10) gFString = "A";
    else if (green == 11) gFString = "B";
    else if (green == 12) gFString = "C";
    else if (green == 13) gFString = "D";
    else if (green == 14) gFString = "E";
    else if (green == 15) gFString = "F";
    else gFString = String.valueOf(green);

    if (rgreen == 10) gSString = "A";
    else if (rgreen == 11) gSString = "B";
    else if (rgreen == 12) gSString = "C";
    else if (rgreen == 13) gSString = "D";
    else if (rgreen == 14) gSString = "E";
    else if (rgreen == 15) gSString = "F";
    else gSString = String.valueOf(rgreen);

    gFString = gFString + gSString;

    blue = b / 16;
    rblue = b % 16;

    if (blue == 10) bFString = "A";
    else if (blue == 11) bFString = "B";
    else if (blue == 12) bFString = "C";
    else if (blue == 13) bFString = "D";
    else if (blue == 14) bFString = "E";
    else if (blue == 15) bFString = "F";
    else bFString = String.valueOf(blue);

    if (rblue == 10) bSString = "A";
    else if (rblue == 11) bSString = "B";
    else if (rblue == 12) bSString = "C";
    else if (rblue == 13) bSString = "D";
    else if (rblue == 14) bSString = "E";
    else if (rblue == 15) bSString = "F";
    else bSString = String.valueOf(rblue);

    bFString = bFString + bSString;

    result = "#" + rFString + gFString + bFString;

    return result;

}
```

My question is: is there a way that I can convert this string result to an int value, that I can use this way:

```
view.setBackgroundColor(0xF82619);
```

Or is ther a way to convert the string to int and than do it (without crash):

```
view.setBackgroundColor(result);
```

Thanks!

Comment: why dont you directly convert int to hex

Comment: Never write a method that converts an int to a hex string value.  This is such a basic task, the language (or base API) will always provide a method (or function) to perform that task.  In java, String.format() is the method; try this: String output = String.format("#%02x%02x%02x", 10, 11, 56);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you string is

```
String col = "0xF82619";
```

try:

```
view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(col));
```

Answer (score 5):

To get an integer you can do

```
int col = (0xff << 24) | ((r&0xff) << 16) | ((g&0xff) << 8) | (b&0xff);
```

Even easier is:

```
int col = Color.rgb(r, g, b);
```

Comment: Henry, it's not working:

int r = 255, g = 40, b = 100;
int col = ((r&0xff) << 16) | ((g&0xff) << 8) | (b&0xff);
view.setBackgroundColor(col);

Comment: Yes, I forgot about the alpha channel. An opaque color has alpha 255. See updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of converting it to first string and then to hex directly convert it to hex by

```
  Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(n), 16);
```

it would increase performance of your code.